# Where did start-stop-daemon store the pid file by default?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, bash, shell, upstart

When I have a upstart script like..

```
exec start-stop-daemon --exec /tmp/test.sh --background --start
```

I suppose will save the `pid` file somewhere and later use it for `stop` or `restart`, right?

So where is the pid file created by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowhere.  Per the `start-stop-daemon` manpage:

> Note: unless --pidfile is specified, start-stop-daemon behaves similar to killall(1).   start-stop-daemon  will  scan the  process table looking for any processes which match the process name, uid, and/or gid (if specified). Any matching process will prevent --start from starting the daemon. All matching processes will be sent the  TERM  signal  (or the  one  specified via --signal or --retry) if --stop is specified. For daemons which have long-lived children which need to live through a --stop, you must specify a pidfile.

Comment: So you mean it will kill all "/tmp/test.sh" in the process list instead?

Comment: I suspect it will killall "test.sh", the path isn't usually part of the process name.

Comment: So seems it is not that reliable if using common scrpt name, e.g. server.sh...

Comment: In that case your script should create a pidfile somewhere when it is run, so you can use `--pidfile /some/where` with `start-stop-daemon`.  Otherwise, if your script doesn't fork, then you can use `--make-pidfile` with `--pidfile` and start-stop-daemon will create one for you.

Comment: Even if I provide --pidfile, how `start-stop-daemon` know the location  when it need to `stop`? Suppose this file should be stored somewhere?

Comment: --pidfile takes an argument: `--make-pidfile --pidfile /some/place`.  You'll have to give the same `--pidfile /some/place` when you want to stop it.